# Execute sh script on linux with php

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm stuck with the following problem:
I try to execute a sh script using php.

My attempts:
I can run other commands. As an example I can run the 'cat' programm to display the script I'd like to execute: `<?php  echo exec("cat /srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh"); ?>`
The following snippets don't work:

```
<?php echo `/srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh`; ?>
<?php echo `sh /srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh`; ?>
<?php exec("sh /srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh"); ?>
<?php exec("/srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh"); ?>
The same with: system(), popen(), proc_open(), passthru(), shell_exec()
```

I tried various file permissions on the script. Even rwxrwxrwx and rwsrwxrwx.
PHP continues execution after the execution as if it worked. No PHP error is generated. When I start the script on the console (like: sh /srv/web/scripts/start_server.sh) it works.
I tested with a simple script, which works on the console but not when I try to execute it with php:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hallo > /srv/web/scripts/file.txt
```

There is no safe-mode enabled. The exec function is nowhere disabled.

As an environment I use ipfire core 71 on an alix board. Apache as httpd and php5 as php interpreter.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What operating system? Redhat/Fedora/CentOS used to have stringent SELinux policies regarding what the apache user (httpd) was allowed to do...

Comment: "ipfire core 71"
It's a debian child if I remember correctly.

Comment: So log in as the apache user and try to execute the scripts from a console. Does it work?. Essentially, un-protected PHP should be able to do the same things as the user it is running as.

Comment: I did let apache as delivered. Using different test the user is "root" (ps aux | grep apache) or "nobody" (other more complicate method I forgot).
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/home/nobody:/bin/false
Could /bin/false be the problem?

Comment: Found the solution now: It's a mix of two problems. Firstly i didn't set the o+x on the directory the script was in, so it could not create files. Secondly I use etherwake in the real script, which has to be executed as root. Simply setting ug+s for /usr/sbin/etherwake worked out. The user apache runs under is nobody, but leaving the console to /bin/false is totaly fine. Thank you very much tucuxi. You brought me to new ideas and because of you I didn't gave up and can be happy now.

Comment: Often happens that the problem is not where you see things fail, but much earlier :-). Also, you may want to add an answer to your own question -- expected, encouraged, and covered in the FAQ.